# fastest method of updating class properties

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a rather large program and as such just going to simplify a bit.

So I have a List (Of Entity), Entity being a custom class with heaps of properties. I have a 1ms timer, which constantly updates this list. In the timer it creates a temporary list from the external source, and if that list is different to the current list, updates the main list.

Now this is where it gets slow, I think. I have A LOT of threads, one for each property of the class which constantly updates that property (the values come externally) and I stop them all, otherwise whilst the list gets updated it will throw all kinds of errors. Then I update the main list with the temp list, and then create new threads again e.g.

```
Prop1Thread = New Thread(AddressOf UpdateProp1)
```

and start them all again.

Pretty much is there a better method I could use? The properties have to be updated in different threads, otherwise it destroys performance. I can't change the way I get the list of entities either. I just really need a better way of handling the updating of the properties of the changing list of Entities.

Comment: "the values come externally...The properties have to be updated in different threads, otherwise it destroys performance."  Are you saying that you are fetching the new values over a network, which introduces I/O latency?  If so, then you probably do want to use multiple threads to fetch the new values.  If not, then can you provide more details?

Comment: They just come from a different program, out of memory, a very old game. Empire Earth if you have heard it. I didn't want to say it because I think I read somewhere that it could be breaking TOS or something and thats not allowed on StackOverFlow, even though the game is 13 years old it still has a community and I'm trying to come up with a ranking system. All the properties are various properties are various values like resources, as I am also trying to implement an anti cheat more like anti glitch, though as the game has a lot of exploitable glitches. The entities are the players.

Comment: In that case, if fetching the values is not slow due to I/O, then creating lots of threads will only hurt performance.  Try using just one background thread to fetch and update all values, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would say: post some code, because there's not really enough information to diagnose anything for sure.

Secondly: it sounds as though you have a lot of threads for your property updating. If you have more threads than you have processors on your machine, you are most likely slowing your code down more than you're speeding it up.

Further, it sounds like you're doing a lot of work work every 1ms on a timer.  That being the case, I would guess that you're thrashing your system too aggressively - unless you're sure that everything you mention in your question is running in < 1ms. Depending on how you're handling the timer, it's possible that you have multiple iterations of your code stacking up, which would also contribute to the loss in performance.

My advice would be:

- drop everything down to just a couple of threads (one for property update handling, one for your timer) - it sounds as though you have far too many
- reduce the frequency of your timer. In fact, get rid of the timer and test against a single iteration to see what your *one-off* update time is, and then bring the timer back in to understand how that's affecting performance (if at all)
- *profile, profile, profile* to understand the problem

Comment: I actually tried to show example code, but it hard because its apart of a big structure. But you have made an excellent point that should've been obvious. I didn't even think for a second that timer would be causing multiple iterations, the worse part is that, in the timer it actually uses the entity code in a new worker thread. So I'm going to scrap the timer, and throw the entity updating into a Do while loop with a thread.sleep, in a new thread. The problem with having 1 thread for property updating is that its too slow and up cpu usage.

Comment: Glad I was of some help. RE property updating: if you have more threads than you have CPUs (and assuming nothing's waiting on disk/network IO or similar) then the threads will be actively fighting eachother for CPU time, and that will be a performance hit. One thread may not be enough, but one thread per property sounds like massive overkill.

Comment: I know with threadpool workers, you could have something crazy like 1024 because of the way vb.net works, or at least I thought so. So I thought I was fairly safe having a like I think 30-40 threads? I was originally using threadpool workers, but you can't stop them quick enough.

Comment: ThreadPool workers aren't one per thread, though - typically the ThreadPool will limit itself to a number of threads that doesn't cause too much contention, and run workers in turn on those threads as necessary.  (`ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` will tell you how many threads it's limiting itself to.) If you're explicitly creating a load of threads yourself, though, you'll get exactly what you ask for... :-)

Comment: In each thread I also have a Thread.Sleep(1) to slow them down a bit, otherwise it destroys everything. So is 30-40 threads super bad? Should I perhaps nail them down to something like 3 or 4 threads, but without the Thread.Sleep? The threads are infinite do while loops also, thats why they have the thread.sleep. When I mentioned the workers I didn't mean I was using them. I'm declaring each thread and setting .isbackground to true. Actually I just properly understood your answer after rereading. Whats a nice amount of normal threads to have?

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep` is just further wasted performance - if you have 40 threads each issuing `Thread.Sleep(1)` every loop, you could be thread switching a lot more often than you need to. The thread switching time is not insignificant! I would definitely start with a single thread and then increase slowly, rather than starting with 30-40.  Out of interest: what is the trigger for the thread doing work? Or is there something to do every time you loop?

Comment: Every iteration of the loop, it goes through the list of Entities and updates the property of each Entity. It goes like this Create List Of Entities > Start Threads (which have do while true loops) > Each thread updates an individual property.